# How to add extra column in csv using python by maintaining the number of delimiters?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

Below is the dataframe generated using python and transfered to csv file. The number of delimiter i.e (|) are 9 as shown below

```
Date|ID|CD|BIN|INTRNL|PCC|IND|CENTRE|TRANS|ENTITY
20221231|APPLE|10004050|BCH_dummy|3505|N|Y|Y|6310|
20221231|APPLE|10004050|BCH_MOTOR|3502|N|Y|Y|6310|

Dataframe:

Date ID CD BIN INTRNL PCC IND CENTRE TRANS ENTITY
20221231 APPLE 10004050 BCH_dummy 3505 N Y Y 6310
20221231 APPLE 10004050 BCH_MOTOR 3502 N Y Y 6310
```

But I want to add an extra column name on the left side of Date column and maintain the same number of delimeter(|) which is 9 as shown below

```
Expected Output in CSV file:

BDR2|Date|ID|CD|BIN|INTRNL|PCC|IND|CENTRE|TRANS|ENTITY
20221231|APPLE|10004050|BCH_dummy|3505|N|Y|Y|6310|
20221231|APPLE|10004050|BCH_MOTOR|3502|N|Y|Y|6310|

df.insert(0, column="BDR2", value='')
df = df.shift(-1, axis = 1)
df.replace("nan",'',inplace=True)
df.to_csv(r"C:\INPUT\df_sample_test.csv",sep='|',index=False)
```

Comment: You can't, the number of delimiters needs to `number of columns - 1`.

Comment: Can you drop that last "ENTITY" column, which seems to be empty (at least for your two example rows)? Then you still have a 10-column table which will have 9 delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, I don't think it's possible.

However, you can *cheat/fake* it by making a one-column `csv` like so :

```
out = (
        pd.read_csv("inputfile.csv", sep="|")
          .rename({"Date": "BDR2|Date"}, axis=1)
          .fillna("").astype(str)
          .pipe(lambda x: x.agg("|".join, axis=1)
                           .to_frame(f'{"|".join(x.columns)}'))
       )

out.to_csv(outputfile.csv, index=False)
```

Output :

```
print(out.to_csv(sys.stdout, index=False))

BDR2|Date|ID|CD|BIN|INTRNL|PCC|IND|CENTRE|TRANS|ENTITY
20221231|APPLE|10004050|BCH_dummy|3505|N|Y|Y|6310|
20221231|APPLE|10004050|BCH_MOTOR|3502|N|Y|Y|6310|
```